# How to fire mousedown event programatically?

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a formpanel and some fields inside it.

I'm registering a mousedown event for form which shows a border to the field. When a mousedown is happening for the otherfield then i'm removing the existing field border and applying it to the current field for which mousedown occured.

For this form I'm adding the fields dynamically.
Now for the newly added field i want to show the border i.e., i want to fire the mousedown event programatically.

Can you please suggest how can i achieve?

Regards
URL

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here is not fire the mouse-down event programatically, but call the function that the mouse-down event uses.

Comment: +1, "firing" a DOM event on an element is very rarely a good idea.